# For which of the candidate gravitation theories has LIGO been able to establish a 5 sigma exclusion of gravitational wave polarization predictions?

Tags: gravity, gravitational-waves, polarization, ligo

In "[Gravitational Wave Polarizations: A test of General Relativity using Binary Black hole mergers](https://thesis.library.caltech.edu/13851/8/Sudhi_thesis.pdf)" the candidate gravitation theories and their gravitational wave polarizations are given in Figure 1.4:

[image: Figure 1.4: The GW polarization predictions of alternative theories of gravity.]

> In this thesis, we explore the possibility of detecting small
> admixtures of vector and/or scalar polarizations in gravitational
> radiation. We explore beyond GR regimes by simulating BBH transient GW signals with tensor, vector and scalar polarization components in a network of five non-co-oriented GW detectors available in the near
> future. We quantitatively determine the detection sensitivity towards small admixtures of vector and/or scalar polarizations in the simulated GW signal.

Which of these theories, if any, has the network of gravitational wave detectors (e.g. [LIGO](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/)) been able to exclude to a 5 sigma significance?

Comment: Since LIGO by itself cannot constrain polarization, the trivial answer is none. Did you mean to ask for The LIGO Virgo network?

Comment: Yes.  Of course.  Corrected.

Comment: I am pretty sure all of the theories have at least one free parameter which describes the strength of the modification from GR, so for a specific theory the question would more be "what's the best upper bound on that free parameter from data." In terms of polarizations, I believe GW170817 is still the best source of constraints, because the EM counterpart means that there is a definite sky position; but the constraints on polarization are still not great. However, based on the abstract, it looks like that thesis is mostly considering what will be possible with a 5 detector network.